# Mosqitto MQTT Broker should reject the connection when CN of the cert and client id mismatch

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Mosqitto MQTT Broker should reject the connection when CN of the cert and client id mismatch, usually devices with proper cert will have same client id and CN name based on our setup but sometimes device might be using other device cert like below. Is there a way to block this in mqtt broker

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? There is a configuration option to use the cn as the client id

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is currently possibly out of the box with mosquitto. As I mentioned in the comments it is possible to force the client id to be the certificate CN to be the client id using the `use_username_as_clientid` and the `use_identity_as_username` but this wouldn't stop a client setting it's own client id.

If you want to enforce that the client sets it's own client id and it matches the certificate CN then you will probably need to write your own authentication plugin.